# N working antennas and M defective ones (combinatorics problem)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**PROBLEM**

Consider a set of $N$ antennas of which $M$ are defective. How many linear orderings are there in which no two defectives are consecutive?

What I can do think of is:  we need to put one defective antenna and then one working antenna and then so on alternating between defecting and working ones. So how many possible ways we can do it?

${n \choose m}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the antenna are identical otherwise, let the positions of the defective antennas be $x_1,x_1+x_2,x_1+x_2+x_3,\ldots,x_1+\ldots +x_m$, 
where $x_1 \geq 1$, $x_i \geq 2$ for $i \geq 2$, and $x_1+\ldots+x_m \leq n$.
This is equivalent to the number of solutions to $y_1+y_2+\ldots+y_m \leq n-m+1$ with $y_i \geq 1$. Can you complete it?

Answer (score 0):

Place all the $N-M$ working antennas in a line. Now there are $N-M+1$ places available for the defective antennas. Therefore, the total ways are$${N-M+1}\choose M$$

Comment: I already know the answer but the question is how?  How do you know in the first place $n-m$ antennas mean $n-m+1$ places?

Comment: @Arnuld By experimentation. Draw out three antennas on a paper. There’s a space available to the left of the first one, to the right of the first one, to the right of the second one, and to the right of the third one. Doing so will ensure that no two defective antennas are adjacent.

Comment: Yes, I did the same before I posted the question. Was just not satisfied. There is no mathematical intuition based solution? Without practically doing it it and without using a formula?

Comment: @Arnuld What’s it not to be satisfied? Are you saying that using formulas doesn’t constitute mathematics?